# API Key security definition 'bearerAuth' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am importing a swagger definition in the AWS API gateway, and its failing  , first I tried

```
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

The error i got was

*Unsupported security definition type 'http' for 'bearerAuth'. Ignoring.*

I changed this to

```
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: apiKey
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

Got the following errors

*Parse issue: attribute components.securitySchemes.bearerAuth.name is missing*
*Parse issue: attribute components.securitySchemes.bearerAuth.in is missing*

finally changed this to

```
securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: apiKey
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: jwt
      name: authorization
      in: header
```

The final error :

*API Key security definition 'bearerAuth' has unexpected name or location. Ignoring.*

unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here

Thanks

Comment: In your last example, try changing `name: authorization` to `name: Authorization`. Also remove `scheme` and `bearerFormat` - these keywords are only used with `type: http` security and aren't used with `type: apiKey`.

Comment: i tired that   
securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header      (got the same error)

Comment: FWIW, I think people are using the `scheme` and `bearerFormat` with the `type: apiKey` because API Gateway doesn't appear to work with `type: http`. So our APIs are using the latter and we set the extra properties as extra info.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I received this error until I set the `x-amazon-apigateway-*` parts of the API definition:

Example of mine (using a custom authorizer):

```json
{
      "type": "apiKey",
      "scheme": "bearer",
      "in": "header",
      "name": "Authorization",
      "bearerFormat": "JWT",
      "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "custom",
      "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
            "type": "token",
            "identitySource": "$request.header.Authorization",
            "authorizerUri": "<lambda uri>",
            "authorizerCredentials": "<iam arn>"
      }
}
```